# Get the changed data selection

Tags: d3.js

My data are an **array of numbers**.

At regular time **numbers are swapped to randomize the array**.

Each number is represented by **a bar in a bar-chart**.

At each step I'd like to highlight the two elements that were swapped by running a simple transition that change their color and opacity (blink effect).

As of now, before swapping I **copy the dataset**, then, when animating the update-selection, I **check if the number has moved** by comparing its value to the value of the previous dataset at the same position: if different I change the color and opacity.

Here is the code:

```
bars.transition()
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return d !== previous[i] ? "green" : "blue"; })
        .attr("opacity", function(d, i) { return d !== previous[i] ? 0.5 : 1; })
    .transition()
        .attr("x", getX)
    .transition()
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("opacity", 1);
```

The "issue" is that all the existing bars are "affected", not only the updated ones.

I have two concerns:

- Though this is not visible (the other bars "move" to the same position and their fill is "changed" to the same color) I guess this is not ideal from a performance point of view because there is a lot of useless processing (with 100 bars 98% of identity operations).
- Moreover the special path of execution for the changed data is interleaved (through conditional statements) with the "do nothing" path, which is clearly not ideal for understanding and maintenance.

_

**Does D3 has such a notion of "changed data"?**

**Is there a more D3 way of doing the same thing?**

_

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D3 way to do this would be to key the data on its values. That is, each changed bar would be a "new" data item and you could handle it accordingly with the `.enter()` and `.exit()` selections, which would give you direct access to what has changed.

However, this wouldn't allow you to easily "move" the bars -- instead of changing the position of one bar, you would remove one and append another at the new position. You could of course hack the enter and exit selections, but that kind of defeats the point.

Instead, I would filter the selection to only contain the bars for which the values have changed and then operate on those. All you need is a call to `.filter()`, the rest of the code can remain unchanged.

```
bars.filter(function(d, i) { return d !== previous[i]; })
    .transition()
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("opacity", 0.5)
.transition()
    .attr("x", getX)
.transition()
    .attr("fill", "blue");
    .attr("opacity", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lars. The data are already identified by their value. The filter function does not work as it does not preserve the original index. But the select function does something similar: `bars.select(function(d, i) { return d !== previous[i] ? this : null; })` Thanks for the idea. If there is no other input within 24h I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: Ah ok, it wasn't clear to me that you needed the index to be preserved. But yes, in that case a subselection is the way to go. I just tend to use filter because it's more intuitive for me.

Comment: It wasn't clear to you for good reason: you couldn't know, it's hidden in `getX`. :) I'd prefer `filter` too because I'm not comfortable using a function like `select` for two different "purposes"; the semantics of `filter` is clear.